# Get revision of a file from Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working with Drive SDK. Once I get the list of revisions of one document, I want to get the link of each revision (to download or to see the document). I do:

```
revisions.getItems().get(i).getSelfLink();
```

Problem is when I open that link on Chrome and I get this JSON:

```
{
 "error": {
 "errors": [
  {
   "domain": "global",
   "reason": "required",
   "message": "Login Required",
   "locationType": "header",
   "location": "Authorization"
  }
 ],
 "code": 401,
 "message": "Login Required"
}
}
```

This is the link of one revision: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0BwATGTGoM7ENalFjTG5ZNGhLTE0/revisions/0BwATGTGoM7ENZ09RVVdCZG9yQ2U2NXY3RXZmNVgvZUo5NXBnPQ

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I have decided to make the canonical link in order to download the revision. This is:

```
String URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=" + 
       ID_DOCUMENT + "&export=download&revid=" + ID_REVISION;
```

It works fine!

Diego.